# Posting a large string to an mvc4 controller within azure failing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an issue with an mvc4 controller (only on a production azure web role)

I have a large svg image about 7mb that I am trying to send back to the server. I have tried 2 approaches both without any luck doing a full form post with the value of the svg file and also an ajax post. Both times the controllers parameter is always null.

I assume its because the size of the string i am trying to send is to big. Example of my code using the ajax approach.

```
        $(".export").on("click", function () {
        var chart = $("#barchart").data("kendoChart");
        var svgString = chart.svg();
        var exportFormat = $(this).data("format");
        if(svgString!=""&&exportFormat!=""){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../SendMyFile",
                data: JSON.stringify(escape(svgString) + "&" + exportFormat),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
```

Is there a config setting I need to do or is it a case of changing my code?
I also made a modification to the web.config

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000">
    </jsonSerialization>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

Any help would be awesome!!

Comment: That's a hell of a lot of data to be sending back. You will probably need to increase the `MaxEntityRequest` in the IIS metabase, however that's a last resort. Is there no other method you can use to do what you need?

Comment: Yes ideally I would like to do this on the server however I don't have that ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside altering your `jsonSerialization` element, you have to also tweak the `httpRuntime` and more precisely the [maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. The default value is 4MB. And while you may have changed this for your local IIS, in Azure you have defaults unless explicitly overridden in your web.config.